# How to set wordpress metabox position

Tags: php, html, wordpress

So I have a custom metabox, and I need it to be after the post title, is there a way to set the position order?

//LE
Doesn't work:

```
//create a variable and store the widget
$widget1 = $wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['information'];

// unset both widgets
unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['information']);

//re insert widget in the order you want
$wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['information'] = $widget1;
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Dashboard_Widgets_API#Advanced%3a_Forcing_your_widget_to_the_top) about forcing your dashboard widget to the top.  The theory can be used for aranging post/page meta boxes.

```
//create a variable and store the widget
$widget1 = $wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['your widget id'];
$widget2 = $wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['other widget id'];

// unset both widgets
unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['your widget id']);
unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['other widget id']);

//re insert widget in the order you want
$wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['other widget id'] = $widget2;
$wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['your widget id'] = $widget1;
```

You can also use jQuery to move the boxes after they are displayed

```
$('#pageparentdiv').prependTo('#normal-sortables');
$('#panel_38').insertAfter('#pageparentdiv');
```

Comment: `//create a variable and store the widget
$widget1 = $wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['information'];

// unset both widgets
unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['information']);

//re insert widget in the order you want
$wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['information'] = $widget1;`  And doesn't work

Comment: The code sample is for dashboard widgets. It would have to be modified for post/page meta boxes, but the theory is still the same. Save meta box as variable, delete meta boxes, insert variables as meta boxes.

Comment: So In my custom post type I need it to be like this: Post title, custom metabox, editor and so on...